# Sandbox iframe attribute isn't preventing redirects in FIrefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, sandbox, breakout

I'm trying to get iFrame sandboxing to work, and Firefox is giving me trouble.

```
<iframe src="" scrolling="no" sandbox=""></iframe>
```

I use jQuery to set the iFrame's `src` attribute to one of several different pages. But my target pages have JavaScript in them that makes them break out of my iFrame. I counter that with the `sandbox` attribute, which is supposed to prevent JavaScript from running inside the iFrame. This works great in Chrome and Internet Explorer, but in Firefox as soon as I load the target page into the iFrame it takes over the whole window.

Firefox's documentation says it fully supports the `sandbox` attribute. Am I doing something wrong? Installing NoScript and telling my browser not to run JavaScript from the target site makes everything work fine, but obviously I don't want Firefox users to have to install an addon before my site will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are manipulating or setting the **sandbox** attribute after the iframe is in the DOM, it will completely ignore the setting. You must set it before the iframe element is added to the DOM.